# Adding ElephantSQL add-on

Tags: cloudcontrol

I've tried to add ElephantSQL add-on to my application using following command and get error:

```
cctrlapp someapp/default addon.add elephantsql.turtle
addon: Billing account required in order to add "elephantsql.turtle".
```

Could someone explain how can I fix it? Is it possible to use postgresql with free plan?

Comment: I think you have to register a credit card to be able to add any addon, even if it's free.

Answer (score 0):

I just didn't pay attention on Billing Accounts section on account screen.